# How to handle CliendId Validation in Refresh Token grant type?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, .net-6.0, refresh-token, openiddict

I have configured the app with openiddict and now enabled the refresh token support.

The server validate's the ClientID to provide the access token for refresh_token grant type.

1. Can we able to get the access token using refresh_token grant type without client_id validation?
2. Any Overriding methods to handle the client_id validation?

I have tried with AllowAnnonymousClients, but it's not working